# Munkres's question - prove hint

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

[image: n]

hello,
I have a solution for this question that uses the provided hint.
My problem is proving the hint.
Will appreciate any help or idea

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358575/covering-space-of-a-regular-space-is-regular

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825060/a-covering-space-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-hausdorff

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651745/is-a-covering-space-of-a-completely-regular-space-also-completely-regular

Comment: Google with "covering space of a locally compact Hausdorff space is locally compact Hausdorff".

Comment: $$p^{-1}(C) \cap V_{\alpha} = p^{-1}(C) \cap \biggl(E \setminus \bigcup_{\beta \neq \alpha} V_{\beta}\biggr)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just note that, as Daniel noted:

$$p^{-1}[C] \cap V_\alpha = p^{-1}[C] \cap \left(E \setminus \bigcup\{V_\beta: \beta \neq \alpha \}\right)$$

which is closed, as we intersect the closed $p^{-1}[C]$ (by continuity of $p$) with the complement of a union of open sets (so also closed).

The left to right inclusion is clear as the sets $V_\alpha$ are disjoint so $V_\alpha \subseteq E \setminus \bigcup\{V_\beta: \beta \neq \alpha \}$ (if a point is $V_\alpha$, it is in none of the others). The right to left is similar.

Now see how you can use this fact to prove the three facts (you might need it for two of them).